# Groovy using variable in import command

Tags: groovy

There was the same question for python language on the web-site, but I need to do the same thing in Groovy:

```
env = System.getenv("INSTANCE")
cp = ${env} + ".Vars"
import "${cp}"
```

This of course doesn't work, but is there a possibility to use a variable inside import command in Groovy? I'm a novice in Groovy and can't figure it out, googled a lot, but without any success. I will be very grateful to anyone who helps.

Answer (score 2):

No you can not import via a string.  But you can load your class there via `Class.forName(cp)` (then then use it e.g. via `newInstance()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, but with a small edition:
    env = System.getenv("INSTANCE")
    cp = "${env}" + ".Vars"
    def cl = Class.forName(cp, true, getClass().classLoader)
    def map = cl.map // This is a map I access then